# Microsoft Graph filter is getting an error of Unsupported Query

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get all users not in a specific domain. I'm using a filter directly from Microsoft's Graph documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=csharp). However, Graph returns an Unsupported Query error. I'm stumped.

Query:

```
            var usersPage = await _graphClient
            .Users
            .Request()
            .Filter("not(endsWith(mail, 'excludeddomain.com'))")
            .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Using some operators such as 'ne' or 'not' require advanced query capabilities. To get the advanced query capabilities you must ["must add the ConsistencyLevel header set to eventual and use the $count=true query string."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=csharp)

Correct syntax:

```
           var usersPage = await _graphClient
            .Users
            .Request(new Option[] { new QueryOption("$count", "true") })
            .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
            .Filter("not(endsWith(mail, 'excludeddomain.com'))")
            .GetAsync();
```